# Thymeleaf form select option dropdown with tab index

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I'm creating a dropdown using thymeleaf as follows:

```
<select id="userLevel" class="form-control" required>
    <option th:each="level : ${levels}" th:text="${level.description}" th:value="${level.id}">
</select>
```

Add the HTML generated by thymeleaf is as follows:

```
<select id="userLevel" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="0">Level 1</option>
    <option value="1">Level 2</option>
    <option value="2">Level 3</option>
    <option value="3">Level 4</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> 
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </button>
  <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(1px, 33px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
    <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio" title="Level 1"><input type="radio" value="0"> Level 1</label></a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio" title="Level 2"><input type="radio" value="1"> Level 2</label></a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio" title="Level 3"><input type="radio" value="2"> Level 3</label></a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio" title="Level 4"><input type="radio" value="3"> Level 4</label></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the tab key is not behaving as expected. I want to be able to press tab once to cycle though each element in the form, but instead I press the tab key once, and the 'select' is focused, and then again and the 'button' is focused.

I have tried adding:

```
tabindex="-1"
```

to the select element, but then it appends it to both the 'select' and the 'button', resulting in:

```
<select id="userLevel" class="form-control" required="" tabindex="-1">
    ...
</select>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> 
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </button>
  ...
</div>
```

And then the tab key skips the element entirely. I want the 'button' to be selected once when the tab key is pressed but not the select, since the button is correctly formatted and is highlighted when it has focus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the `btn-group` div and its content generated? Is it generated by some plugin?

Comment: I thought this was generated by Thymeleaf - its not my code though so I'm not sure. The fact that you are asking me makes me think that it isn't.

Comment: Thymeleaf is only used in the first code fragment to loop through `levels` and generate options. There must be additional code afterwards to generate the `btn-group`, If no html is immediatly under, it might be generated and appended after the select by a fauly feature which is supposed to enhance the style of the dropdown but while doing so generates a button with the same tabindex as the original select. Try to identify this feature and see where that leads.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I thought this was purely a Thymeleaf feature. I've had a look at the pom but there are no obvious plugins. I'll keep searching but at least I'm closer to know what I'm looking for now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. After knowing what I was looking for I found the culprit, the plugin "bootstrap-multiselect.js" was the one adding the div.
I have removed the plugin and it is now working as expected. I will add an answer for anyone else experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Alexandru I have discovered the issue.

I was also using the plugin "bootstrap-multiselect.js" which was generating the div element, along with Thymeleaf which was generating the select element.

I removed the plugin and now everything is working as expected - just the select and options are generated and the tab button behaves as expected.